# How to count consecutive rows with same value for a column in a database using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My App consists of a notification module. If the notifications are consecutively arrived from a same user, I would like to show "n notifications from john doe".

eg:

```
5 notifications from john doe
2 notification from james
4 notofications from john doe
```

How would I count these consecutive rows with same value in a column using django orm?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have a model `Notifications` and another model named `User`. Then you can group by `user_id`

```
q=Notifications.objects.filter(user__id=1).values('user__first_name', 'user_id').annotate(c=Count('user__id'))
```

Comment: But that doesn't count [strictly] consecutive rows of Notifications model. It simple counts total no. of notifications by a User. Please read my question.

Comment: Add your model definition to question

Answer (score 0):

Just as Shafikur's answer above but I suppose you will have something to denote that the notification is new or hasn't been read. So let's add one more piece to the filter:

```
q=Notification.objects.filter(user__id=1, status='new').values('user__first_name', 'user_id').annotate(c=Count('user__id'))
```

It's not certain how you track the new notifications in your model, so this is just a rough guess which you should be able to apply to your particular case